# Maven doesn't find artifact on GitHub

Tags: java, maven

I'm currently in the process of uploading my library to my own repository hosting on GitHub. I have both the .jar and .pom files in the correct locations on GitHub:

com/github/polyrocketmatt/kmt/0.0.4/KMT-0.0.4.jar

com/github/polyrocketmatt/kmt/0.0.4/KMT-0.0.4.pom

However, when I want to include this jar in another project, maven can not resolve the artifact. Another library of mine however, has the exact same structure on GitHub and is able to be resolved.

com/github/polyrocketmatt/Game/3.0.7/Game-3.0.7.jar

com/github/polyrocketmatt/Game/3.0.7/Game-3.0.7.pom

This library does contain .sha1 and .md5 files, so my first question if those are necessary and if so, how I can generate them automatically from the jar and pom. You can take a look at the whole structure [here](https://github.com/PolyRocketMatt/Warehouse). Is there something I'm missing? I've been stuck at this for a few hours now. The KMT project itself is a gradle project but I want to host the Jar on my GitHub so it can be used in other Gradle/Maven projects.

Comment: What URL are you using as the repo? If it's the one in the readme of your project then it's 404ing. Wouldn't it be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PolyRocketMatt/Warehouse/main/ ? I've never seen this "maven repo in a github repo" done before. Do you have reason to suspect it will work, or are you just hoping if you emulate the structure then it will work? Why don't you use [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/)? They build and serve artifacts for free. There's also [Github Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages) (haven't used it)

Comment: I'll look into Jitpack. For the Game artifact, this approach is working. And yes I am hoping that it will work by emulating the structure. Currently the .pom is auto-generated from a small script. GitHub Packages requires me to use a Github Token and I don't want that. I'll try the URL you provided

EDIT: The URL you provided sadly didn't work

Comment: "*my first question if those are necessary*" According to the docs, yes. ["For each file that is the repository there **must be** a file containing the checksum of the file, typically md5 or sha1"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) "*and if so, how I can generate them automatically*" http://checksum-maven-plugin.nicoulaj.net/index.html"